# Dart pub is not downloading dependencies

Tags: dart

I had moved my Dart Project to another folder, with the same folder structure, however, now, I'm receiving the following message:

```
Running pub install ...
Pub install failed, [1] Resolving dependencies...
Could not find package "dartflash 0.6.3" at http://pub.dartlang.org.
```

Here is my pubspec.yaml:

```
name:  Chronium
description:  A framework for doing Chrono like games.

dependencies:
  dartflash: 0.6.3
```

And pubspec.lock:

```
{"packages":{"dartflash":{"version":"0.6.3","source":"hosted","description":"dartflash"}}}
```

And the file structure:

[image: file structure]

The website (http://pub.dartlang.org/) is accessible from the browser.
I'm on dart (Dart Editor version 0.2.9_r16323). Do someone knows what is happening?

Comment: have you tried running pub -v install on the command line from your project's directory? it should give you much more useful error messages?

Comment: It looks like this question was answered correctly. Do you mind giving it the green checkmark?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to [Seth Ladd post](https://plus.google.com/118397406534237711570/posts/E5mPPJAW8qh), this should be fixed now :

> If you were having troubles with pub.dartlang.org, we're happy to report that we've fixed the issue. Many apologies for the temporary downtime. Looks like it was an issue with the server pointing to the wrong data store. Thanks for all the reports, the pub is open again!

Comment: Seth is correct. We accidentally misconfigured the pub server. Sorry! It's fixed now.